# CKeditor forcePasteAsPlainText not working in 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, wysiwyg, ckeditor, fckeditor

I've heard mixed responses about this working/not working . Mine happens to not work since I've upgraded.

I upgraded rails by using a rails plugin that install rails 3.2.

http://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor

For non-rails users, this basically just installs the latest version of CKeditor with an external yaml file for handling file management. But at a heart, CKeditor is unblemished.

But I made sure my disk was completely clean of any old CKeditor before reinstalling.

Also, I have in their own isolated environments tried pasting into their _samples they offer this :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        //<![CDATA[

            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
                {
                    fullPage : true
                });
            CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true ;

        //]]>
        </script>
```

This would have worked fine in their previous additions.

Has anyone else had this problem, and had it solved?

This is in regards to the `config.js`:

```
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

**Update**

I tried completely uninstalling this several times and putting it back together. Without touching anything just adding forcePasteAsPlainText = true; into the config and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer on stackoverflow ever :

It does work. It just doesn't have a popup anymore 3.1 +